# How to push/insert key value pair list into a list in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list where I am trying to push in a another list, but it keeps throwing error

```
List Products;

for(final i productsFromApi){
      var tmpArray = [];

      tmpArray['name'] = i['name'];
      tmpArray['price'] = i['price'];
      tmpArray['quantity'] = i['quantity'];

      Products.add(tmpArray);
 }

 print('final list of products');
 print(products); // throws an error: add called on null
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to initialize your list

```
List products = [];

for(final i in productsFromApi){
      var productMap = {
          'name': i['name'],
          'price': i['price'],
          'quantity': i['quantity'],
      }

      products.add(productMap);
 }

 print('final list of products');
 print(products);
```

You should consider typing your lists because if you are not careful enough, your current code can cause errors.
Something like this:

```
List<Product> products = [];
Product myProduct = Product(name: "Product 1", price: 2.0, quantity: 3);
products.add(myProduct);
```

Comment: thanks for the swift answer, can I not do it without defining product class?

Comment: @Mikethetechy It is not mandatory, but if you are going to be using that List around your app, using a Product class will probably save you from commiting mistakes using `dynamic` types.

Comment: @Mikethetechy use List<dynamic> and go on :)

Comment: not mandatory?so I can just define  `List <Product>`  as Product type without actually having a product class?

Comment: @Mikethetechy What I mean is that you can keep using `List` which is the same as `List<dynamic>`. Not mandatory because you are free to keep using `dynamic`. Just be careful using it. Also, the Dart compiler and the future you will be glad if you choose the class way of things :)  Remember to close the issue if it helped.

Comment: @Martyns, thank you! the key here was setting `List products = [];` without setting it to empty list it wasn't working also please change one thing in your answer, instead of `var tmpArray = []` it should be `var tmpArray; `. then instead of assigning 
`tmpArray['name'] = i['name'];` 
it should be an object: 
`tmpArray = {'name':i['name'],'price': i['price'],'quantity':i['quantity']}`.

Please switch those 2 up and let's mark this the answer

Comment: @Mikethetechy Updated!

Comment: What is product From API ? I didn't get that